# GAE datastore JOIN + GROUP BY

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

> **NOTE : i have seen the JOIN in GAE related posts** but GROUP BY in my
>   requirements made me make a new post and I have made a solution of my own which I wanted to check how good is it

---

**Datastore Entities properties and types (database)**

1. **Entity** : PartyEntity *lets call this as a*

   - String partyName
   - String partyId
   - BlobKey image
2. **Entity** : InsertEntity *lets call this as b*

   - String partyIdentifier
   - String name
   - String constituency

---

**Objective**

```sql
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b on a.partyId = b.partyIdentifier GROUP BY b.constituency;
```

---

*below I shall answer my question , THE CODE WORKS FINE DO ADVICE ME ANY CHANGES OR BETTER WAYS (I am just a student)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution I made is as follows** , *do advice any changes or better ways*

> // SELECT * FROM a (PartyEntity holds unique partyId)
>   **and** for each partyId SELECT * FROM b

```
private List<ListDisplay> initData() {

        DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
                .getDatastoreService();

        List<ListDisplay> data = new ArrayList<ListDisplay>();

        Query query = new Query("PartyEntity");
        PreparedQuery preparedQuery = datastore.prepare(query);
        List<Entity> entities = preparedQuery.asList(FetchOptions.Builder
                .withDefaults());

        for (Entity entity : entities) {

            String PARTY_ID = (String) entity.getProperty("partyId");

            // fetch from another
            Query query2 = new Query("InsertEntity");
            Filter filterByPartyId = new Query.FilterPredicate(
                    "partyIdentifier", FilterOperator.EQUAL, PARTY_ID);
            query2.setFilter(filterByPartyId);
            PreparedQuery preparedQuery2 = datastore.prepare(query2);

            List<Entity> entities2 = preparedQuery2.asList(FetchOptions.Builder
                    .withDefaults());

            for (Entity entity2 : entities2) {
                ListDisplay display = new ListDisplay();
                display.setPartyId((String) entity.getProperty("partyId"));
                display.setPartyName((String) entity.getProperty("partyName"));
                display.setImage((BlobKey) entity.getProperty("image"));
                display.setName((String) entity2.getProperty("name"));
                display.setConstituency((String) entity2
                        .getProperty("constituency"));
                data.add(display);
            } // end loop entity2

        } // end loop entity

        return data;
    }
```

---

> // GROUP BY constituency clause part

```
public HashMap<String, List<ListDisplay>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<ListDisplay>> data = new HashMap<>();
        List<ListDisplay> list = initData();

        for (ListDisplay d : list) {
            // if null add
            if (data.get(d.getConstituency()) == null) {
                List<ListDisplay> internal = new ArrayList<>();
                internal.add(d);
                data.put(d.getConstituency(), internal);
            }
            // else modify
            else {
                List<ListDisplay> hashlist = data.get(d.getConstituency());
                hashlist.add(d);
                data.remove(d.getConstituency());
                data.put(d.getConstituency(), hashlist);
            }
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: If you have working code, you probably want to post it to Code Review instead of StackOverflow http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndyG how do i move it now ?